# Android TabLayout start activity on the second tab

Tags: android, tabs, android-tablayout

I've got a default Tabbed Activity in Android which has standard "Section 1", "Section 2" and "Section 3" tabs. When the app runs, it starts at tab 1, and I wanted to know how to make it start at tab 2 (the middle one). Some solutions that I've seen propose this:

> actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(1);

But this is deprecated, and when I've read the official doc (https://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation.html), it has nothing on manipulating TabLayout, it only talks about "Back" and "Up" buttons. Any ideas on how can I solve my problem or where can I find a decent tutorial?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as an example you can select 3th tab in this way :

```
tabLayout.getTabAt(3).select();
```